# Is it possible to model a scalable Follower/Following relationship in Azure Cosmos DB?

Tags: c#, azure, nosql, azure-cosmosdb, scalability

Suppose I have a model class that looks like this:

```
public class Relationship
{
  public Guid PartitionKey { get; set; }

  public Guid Id { get; set; }

  public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
}
```

- `PartitionKey` is the partition key of the `Relationship` container, and it is represented by the user id of the person who is being followed. (receiver)
- `Id` is the id of the container and it is represented by the user id of the person who follows the other user. (sender)

This model ensures that the same `Id` cannot be added to the same `PartitionKey` so that the follower/following relationship can only be created once between two users. It also allows me to easily look up the list of all followers for a specific person, which is crucial.

The problem is that each logical partition is limited to 10 GB of data. Considering the actual `Relationship` model is likely to have more properties and there is automatic indexing that happens behind the scenes and some users have millions of followers, this limit will be hit and make it impossible to allow new relationships for the same partition key.

How would one design this model on Cosmos DB so that it is truly scalable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard approach here is to shard your data across multiple partitions manually, usually with a [synthetic partition key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/synthetic-partition-keys) made from multiple items put together.

A simple strategy is to use an integer field in the user record to keep track of the number of "buckets" that are used to store all of the follower records and then send queries to each bucket partition as needed. The number of buckets can be incremented as the data grows.

For example, the partition key would be constructed as `[user_id]+[follower_bucket_count]`. You can also maintain counts per each bucket for more advanced load balancing but that's probably unnecessary to start.

Comment: Thanks. I've thought of this approach, but it's also getting rid of any validation check like unique followers per user. I'd have to query every bucket to see if user A is already following user B before committing the follow transaction to the latest bucket. My concern is that, due to concurrency issues, some records might end up being duplicated. Any opinion on this?

Comment: You can use a stored procedure or Azure function working on a queue to do this in the background. It can do a check for the follower record and only update if it doesn't exist. Most accounts will never get past a single partition so you're not really doing that many extra checks. You can also use the Table API and not worry about partitions at all. Just use the partitionkey+rowkey as the user + follower combo.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, all follow requests are queued and a SP/Function serializes the processing work to avoid duplicate records. This can work assuming the queue doesn't become congested. I'll have to look into the Table API more. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it's a common and recommended approach to use the rest of the Azure platform to get the most out of Cosmos DB with change feeds, Functions and UDFs. The queue processing time depends on your db/collection throughput but strong consistency is per-partition and scales with the number of partitions (which you have set to at least 1 per user) so it's unlikely to become a bottleneck. Functions can also retry automatically if there's no enough throughput provisioned. You can also use a separate function to watch the queue depth and increase throughput automatically.